# Vector Fields on $\mathbf R^2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $X : \mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R^2$ be a no-zero smooth vector field. I want to show (without background about vector bundles or manifolds, just if possible differentiable calculus in $\mathbf R^n$) that there is a smooth function $\psi : \mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R^2$ such that $ d_p\psi(X_p)$ is constant $\forall\ p \in \mathbf R^2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using the Mobius band?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

If such a function $\psi$ exists then $\psi$ takes the integral curves of $X$ to a family of parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This puts strong restrictions on the family of integral curves. For instance, the orbit space of $X$ - meaning the quotient space obtained by collapsing each integral curve to a point - must be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

However, there are counterexamples where the orbit space of $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. For example, you can put the universal cover of [this foliation](https://inspirehep.net/record/1211130/files/foliation-torus.png) in each horizontal strip $\mathbb{R} \times [n-1,n]$. The resulting orbit space is not even Hausdorff, let alone homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.